# How to check multiple conditions with ternary operator in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to change style based on route with the help of react router. So I want the description route to be orange color when user is in description route , white color when user is in teacher-add-course route & green when at others route but my last condition is not rendering when I am at others route. I have tries the conditions with the ternary operator. Can anyone help?

> I have tried writing the condition with the ternary operator & it worked when I am at the teachers-add-course route & description route but when I am in other routes like requirement the condition is not applying.

```
import React from 'react';
import { FaBookOpen } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../asset/css/Teachers-overview/TeachersDashboardSidebar.css'

const TeachersDashboardSidebar = () => {
    let location = useLocation()
    console.log(location.pathname);
    return (
        <div className='sidebar-container'>
            <div className='sidebar-content-wrapper'>
                <div className='overview-wrapper'>
                    <div className='d-flex flex-column align-items-center'>
                            <div className= {`${location.pathname=== '/teacher-add-course'? 'progress-book-icon bg-orange':'progress-book-icon bg-complete'}`}>
                                <FaBookOpen className="text-white " />
                            </div>
                        <div className={`${location.pathname==='/teacher-add-course'? 'candle-basic':'candle-success'}`}></div>
                    </div>
                    <Link to="/teacher-add-course"><span className="text-semilight font-weight-bold mt-2 ml-3">Overview</span></Link>
                </div>
                <div className='bold d-flex'>
                    <div className='d-flex flex-column align-items-center'>
                            <div className={`${location.pathname=== '/teacher-add-course/description'?'bg-orange':'teacher-add-course'?'progress-book-icon':'bg-complete'} `}>
                                <FaBookOpen className="text-white " />
                            </div>
                        <div className={`${location.pathname==='/teacher-add-course/description'? 'candle-basic':'candle-success'}`}></div>
                    </div>
                    <Link to="/teacher-add-course/description"><span className="text-semilight font-weight-bold mt-2 ml-3">Description</span></Link>
                </div>
                <div className='text-warning bold d-flex'>
                    <div className='d-flex flex-column align-items-center'>
                            <div className={`${location.pathname=== '/teacher-add-course/requirements'? 'progress-book-icon bg-orange': '/teacher-add-course/gallery'? 'progress-book-icon bg-complete':'progress-book-icon'}`}>
                                <FaBookOpen className="text-white " />
                            </div>
                        <div className={`${location.pathname==='/teacher-add-course/requirements'? 'candle-basic':'candle-success'}`}></div>
                    </div>
                    <Link to="/teacher-add-course/requirements"><span className="text-semilight font-weight-bold mt-2 ml-3">Requirements</span></Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TeachersDashboardSidebar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write out the entire comparison for each branch.

```js
<div className={`${location.pathname === '/teacher-add-course/requirements'? 'progress-book-icon bg-orange': location.pathname === '/teacher-add-course/gallery'? 'progress-book-icon bg-complete':'progress-book-icon'}`}>
```

Note that the template literal is not needed here; you can directly pass the result of the conditional operator to the `className`.

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. I am trying to solve it for two days now but couldn't figure it out. I have applied your condition & it worked perfectly. But I would like to know another thing if you don't mind. Let's say you are comparing a condition like this :  if this ? 'output' : if this || this ? 'output' : 'final output'. So how would you compare two or conditions in a ternary operator. I hope I was able to explain.

Comment: @MehediHasan No problem. To compare two conditions, just combine them with the logical or operator, e.g. `condA ? 'output1' : condB || condC ? 'output2' : 'output3'`.

Comment: Really appreciate your time bro. Thanks a lot.